# Losing bytes of memory working with pointers to structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I work with a structure that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int size; // Will be the size of *p
    int *p;
} shi;
```

And, for this example, I create a couple of pointers to structures, `shi *example` and `shi example1`.

Then I write 3 functions, which will be examples for this question:

**1.** One function that will build the structures and its `*p` arrays, that will look like this:

```
void build(shi **example, shi **example2) {
    *example = malloc(sizeof(shi));
    (*example)->size = 3;
    (*example)->p = malloc((*example)->size*sizeof(int));
    
    *example2 = malloc(sizeof(shi));
    (*example2)->size = 6;
    (*example2)->p = malloc((*example2)->size*sizeof(int));
}
```

**2.** Another function that will be an intermediary. In this example it will only call the third function:

```
void intermediary(shi **example, shi **example2) {
    // This is a recursive function
    // At some point, will call rebuild(), which will take one position from
    // the p array of example and put it into example2
    rebuild(example,example2);
}
```

**3.** A third function that will interchange the last element of `example->p` with the last element of `example2->p`.

```
void rebuild(shi **example, shi **example2) {
    // Passes last position from example->p to example2->p  
    (*example2)->size++;
    (*example2)->p = realloc((*example2)->p,(*example2)->size*sizeof(int));

    // Last position of example->p = last position of example2->
    (*example2)->p[(*example2)->size-1] = (*example)->p[(*example)->size-1];

    (*example)->size--;
    (*example)->p = realloc((*example)->p,(*example)->size*sizeof(int));
}
```

Well, in my main, I call `build()` and `intermediary()`, passing the adresses of my structures, and it all works fine (compiles and does what it has to do), so -as this is something for school- I will probably get a decent mark.

The problem is that, just to know how to do things right, I want to make it "better", so I've run the program with valgrind, and I got a bunch of errors.

I'd appreciate if you could give any hint on what am I doing wring - or could do better.

- You can see the complete code I made for this example [here](http://ideone.com/IRkQt4).
- And the output valgrind gave me [here](http://pastebin.com/awMLGVSK).

**edit**

There was a mistake in the code. New code is [here](http://ideone.com/RyEqQR) and new valgrind output [here](http://pastebin.com/sXQMXZYQ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NOTE: Suppose that at some point I initialize the values for every element of the `p` arrays.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it is to improve working code, it should be asked on CodeReview

Comment: @SergeBallesta It compiles, but has undefined behavior, so "it works" hardly applied to this code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : It looks like I've read that too fast ...

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned values from call to the malloc() function, when using realloc, always use a temporary target, check (!=NULL) the temporary target to assure successful operation before assigning to the actual target.  Otherwise, the original pointer to allocated memory will be lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: the function main() always has an 'int' return type.  also, the last statement in main() should be 'return(0);'

Comment: As programs get bigger and/or expand into multiple files, the topology of having all the sub functions listed before they are called will not work.  Suggest always use prototypes for the sub functions.  And, generally, the top/first function in a file should be calling the sub functions within that file.  I.E. function main() listed first and the sub functions later in the file.

Comment: I work with prototypes in my original project.

Answer (score 1):

When your `rebuild` function does this

```
(*example2)->p = realloc((*example)->p,(*example)->size*sizeof(int));
//       ^                        ^             ^
//      #2                       #1            #1
```

two things happen:

- The pointer `(*example)->p` becomes invalid, because `realloc`-ed pointer is assigned to `p` of `example2`, and
- The data in the block previously pointed to by `(*example2)->p` is lost, because you did not `free()` it, and now the pointer is gone.

I think this is a copy-paste error, and you meant to write

```
(*example2)->p = realloc((*example2)->p,(*example2)->size*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: That's why copy-pasting is dangerous, and having number-prefixed variable names even more so.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge I suspect that's the error that you have in the code that you ran through valgrind. When you fix this error on your local system and rerun, valgrind should give you different output.

Comment: Fixed the error, and posted new versions of both the code and the valgrind output.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge It looks like valgrind output has not changed between the runs, which does not look right.

Comment: I checked again and yes, it gives the exact same output.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge This does not make any sense - valgrind will give you a different output after the fix. Even the regular output [before](http://ideone.com/1c0bYA) and [after](http://ideone.com/sFoHum) the fix are different: before the fix there is a read of freed data and a double-free, with printing of junk in between, while the fixed code works like a clockwork.

Comment: Runned it through c9.io and it and valgrind gave no error. Nothing makes sense... I checked if there is any mistake like the one you saw in my original program, and there is not, but I still have errors in it when I run valgrind.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge Are you running valgrind locally, using the same updated code that you posted to ideone? Try making a new file with the code from [here](http://ideone.com/sFoHum), and runnng it through valgrind. There should be no errors.

Comment: this code has the problem of using the returned value from realloc() without first checking that the realloc() was successful.  If realloc() fails, then the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: @user3629249 I agree that this is a very common problem that needs to be fixed, but so is the absence of NULL-checking of malloc results. This error has nothing to do with the valgrind issue the OP is describing, though, because both his `realloc` calls succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I see. First, field *p* is a pointer to an *int*, but you are using it as a pointer to a *struct shi*. The second thing is more minor but should be noted. One some computer the size of a pointer may be larger than the size of a pointer. In structs, you should put the field that has the largest size first. The 3rd most minor thing is that for representing sizes of malloc'd objects, the type *size_t* is generally used. See the manual page for malloc().

With those in mind change the definition of shi to:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // Look at man page for malloc()
typedef struct shi_tag {
    size_t size; // Will be the size of *p
    struct shi_tag *p;
} shi;
```

Comment: I understand what you say, but I don't see how to rewrite the code in order to fit this new declaration of the `shi` type. Of course if I only change that declaration, as expected, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: I've been making some tests. I still have memory leaks.